# Get input value from child component with react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

could someone explain to me how I can update a property of an object through a child component in React?

Giving a bit of context: I have a form (using React Hook Form) in the parent component. After it's filled out and submited. I perform some operations on the data that ultimately result in an array of objects. The objects in this array have a property that starts at zero, and only after displaying the results of these operations on the screen, I want the user to input a value for each combination, thus updating its value.(in a second form)

In other words, I map through this array of objects (in the parent component) and render what would be a card (a child component), passing the current object as props.

This card is inside a second form (I'm not sure if this was the best approach), and within the card, the combinations derived from the initial form submission are being rendered, with an input for each combination in this card.

My goal is to, upon clicking the submit button of the second form, retrieve these values from the card's inputs for each respective combination and update this value in my initial array (or generate a new updated array).

```
<form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitMultiple)}>
        <div className="display">
          <div className="multiple-bet-container">
            {randomBets.map((betCombination, index) => (
              <MultipleBetBox key={index} betCombination={betCombination} />
            ))}
          </div>
          {randomBets.length > 0 && (
            <button className="btn" type="submit">
              Aplicar Apostas
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </form>
```

This would be the second form, where randomBets is the array of objects generated through the first form. I'm not sure if using two forms was the most intelligent approach.

Each betcombination has a betAmount value that should be updated when the user clicks the second form submit button.

In my research, I've only seen this type of updating done using useState, with onChange. However, I think using useState might be poor. Again, I'm not sure if using two forms was the most intelligent approach because I need an initial submission to generate the combinations before updating the values of each combination.

The point is not to keep re-rendering as the value changes, just get the input values and assign to the respective betCombination once. And of course get the updated array in the parent component.

Comment: You can have a look at [`useFormContext`](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useformcontext) . It might match with your use case.